# Can't execute mongo command from C# driver when I permisions

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I just added user authentication to my monngodb replica set and now I'm getting a MongoCommandException.

> Command 'listDatabases' failed: not authorized on admin to execute command { listDatabases: 1 } (response: { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { listDatabases: 1 }", "code" : 13 })

What's odd is I can log into mongo in the terminal with the same user and it works just fine.

Here is my user:

```
....    
{
    "_id" : "admin.rulesEngineDBAdmin",
    "user" : "rulesEngineDBAdmin",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "dbOwner",
            "db" : "rules-engine"
        },
        {
            "role" : "clusterAdmin",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
....
```

According to http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/:

> clusterAdmin combines the privileges granted by the clusterManager, clusterMonitor,
>   andhostManager... clusterMonitor provides access to the listDatabases command.

Here is when I run it from the terminal:

```
rules_engine:PRIMARY> db.auth("rulesEngineDBAdmin", "rulesEngineDBAdmin");
1
rules_engine:PRIMARY> db.runCommand( { listDatabases: 1 } )

{
    "databases" : [
            {
                    "name" : "admin",
                    "sizeOnDisk" : 83886080,
                    "empty" : false
            },
            {
                    "name" : "local",
                    "sizeOnDisk" : 1157627904,
                    "empty" : false
            }
    ],
    "totalSize" : 1241513984,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

But when I run this code:

```
doesRulesEngineDbExists = Server.DatabaseExists(databaseName);
```

With this connection string:

```
mongodb://rulesEngineDBAdmin:rulesEngineDBAdmin@...
```

I get this MongoCommandException:

```
Command 'listDatabases' failed: not authorized on admin to execute command
{ listDatabases: 1 }
( response: 
    { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command 
        { listDatabases: 1 }", "code" : 13 
    }
)
```

If anyone has encountered this before, I'd love to know what's going on, and what I can do to fix it.

Comment: did you solve this? I'm running on a similar problem with dropDatabase, with roles like dbOwner and root.

Comment: For me it ended up being a mistake on my part. I hadn't added "authorization: enabled" to my configuration file under the security section, because that part was not mentioned in the tutorial that i was following (All i had was the keyfile). So it looked like I was able to connect, but I couldn't execute any commands.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

This ended up being a mistake on my part. I hadn't added "authorization: enabled" to my configuration file under the security section, because that part was not mentioned in the tutorial that i was following (All i had was the keyfile). So it looked like I was able to connect, but I couldn't execute any commands.